# How to bend shapes into letters in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

I'm trying to reproduce this:

[image]

I have sort of got it by redrawing with the pen but it isn't what I think I should be doing and it isn't as smooth. I think I can do better by trying to learn to bend these shapes properly.

Can someone point in to the correct steps?

Comment: Pen tool is the proper way. It simply takes practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No question in my mind that the sample you've shown is hand drawn and not a 3D render or something. There are ways to make building something like this a little easier on yourself though.

**Draw a path, with a thick stroke and rounded end caps:**

[image]

**Select the path, then go to <kbd>Object > Path > Outline Stroke</kbd>:**

[image]

**Slide your original path over a bit and adjust it until it lines up:**

[image]

**Select your paths and <kbd>Pathfinder > Divide</kbd>. After a little cleanup and some gradient fills, voila:**

[image]

I'll admit, mine is a little rushed and kind of ugly, but it shows how you can create the foundation of a shape like that in just a minute or so.

Comment: +1 I was able to follow these steps with a few differences but it certainly got me in the right direction. Thanks.